# Showing the existence of two spherical surfaces to indirectly prove the method of images working in the setup of a charge and a spherical conductor

Tags: electrostatics, method-of-images

I was trying to show that in the field lines of the setup of two charges lets say $q_1$ and $q_2$ ,distance between then is $z$ where $q_1q_2 <0$ . We can always draw **two imaginary spherical surfaces** not necessarily with any one them acting as centre. Such that the electric field lines are always normal to the spherical surface.

> My progress was that i wrote field equation , but i dont know how to show that a sphere is there or not . My main motto for showing the above fact was to show that from that : we can easily say that in a setup of a spherical conductor with a charge inside or outside we can always have the field lines inside/outside to be as if coming from a imaginary charge kept outside/inside the spherical conductor at some unique distance as a **corollary** which shows the method of images working . [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can actually prove this directly. Are you familiar with [Appollonian circles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_circles)? This will solve your problem and in general explains why the method of image works with a sphere.

Hope this helps and tell me if you need more details.